# how to streaming data from azure eventhub to delta table using spark

Tags: delta-lake

I am using spark of version 3.0.3 and scala of version 2.12.10.I am going to stream data through eventhub to deltatable .

writing streaming data from eventhub to delta table:
devicesDF.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "/delta/events/table").start("/delta/table")

```
scala>devicesDF.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "/delta/events/table").start("/delta/table")
res0:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@70cef1d3
```

while executing the above code,the error i'm getting is:

```
scala> 22/09/24 11:47:46 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 651c88cf-0098-42b5-858d-a32ee9fecfdf, runId = 96fb3c81-79c3-492f-9be4-19235651a6a3] terminated with error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/compat/java8/FutureConverters$
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.utils.RetryUtils$.$anonfun$retryJava$1(RetryUtils.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.utils.RetryUtils$.org$apache$spark$eventhubs$utils$RetryUtils$$retryHelper$1(RetryUtils.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.utils.RetryUtils$.retryScala(RetryUtils.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.utils.RetryUtils$.retryJava(RetryUtils.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.ClientConnectionPool.org$apache$spark$eventhubs$client$ClientConnectionPool$$borrowClient(ClientConnectionPool.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.ClientConnectionPool$.borrowClient(ClientConnectionPool.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.client(EventHubsClient.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.liftedTree1$1(EventHubsClient.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCountLazyVal$lzycompute(EventHubsClient.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCountLazyVal(EventHubsClient.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCount(EventHubsClient.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.partitionCount(EventHubsSource.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.$anonfun$maxOffsetsPerTrigger$4(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.$anonfun$maxOffsetsPerTrigger$2(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.<init>(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider.createSource(EventHubsSourceProvider.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Similar error here. It appeared to be Java / library versions. Perhaps check required libraries for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718116/transform-scala-future-to-completablefuture-error

Comment: You might want to split the streaming and delta pieces to work out which one of these is throwing the error

Comment: what version of eventhubs connector is used?

Comment: Looks like a version incompatibility error.  Is it possible you're using a eventhubs JAR that was compiled with Scala 2.11?

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions, I was missing some jar files (such as scala-java8-compat , proton-j) due to which those error occurred .

Comment: @zainab - can you please answer your own question?  That way other users will be able to easily find the answer if they run into this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue ... I did install scala_java8_compat_2_12_1_0_2.jar - as I was using Runtime with Scala 12 ... and it works fine